# The Branch Schema of a Subgroup of the Modular Group

Tags: manifolds, normal-subgroups, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, modular-group

Let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of the modular group $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

What is the best and easiest way to grasp the notion of the **Branch Schema** of the subgroup $\Gamma$.

Why do we have only four cases for it when $\Gamma$ is a **normal** subgroup of **finite index** of the modular group $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ (that are $(1,1,n)$, $(1,3,n)$, $(2,1,n)$ and $(2,3,n)$ where $n$ is a natural number)?

Why, in the first three cases $(1,1,n)$, $(1,3,n)$ and $(2,1,n)$, is the space $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$ simply connected (where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane)?

R. C. Gunning. **Lectures on Modular Forms**. Pages **12** and **13**
[image]
[image]

Comment: No idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Please provide details on the meaning of "branch schema"; that terminology is not standard.

Comment: @reuns check the question again please

Comment: @LeeMosher check the question again please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the branched covering $\Gamma\backslash \Bbb{H}^*\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\backslash \Bbb{H}^*$ (where $\Bbb{H}^*=\Bbb{H}\cup\Bbb{Q}\cup i\infty$)

eg. the holomorphic map $$f:\Gamma z\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z})z$$

It is locally biholomorphic (unramified) everywhere except maybe at $f^{-1}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) i\infty), f^{-1}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) i),f^{-1}( SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) e^{2i\pi /3})$.

Proof: making a special case for $i\infty$, then this is the points where the branched covering $\Bbb{H}\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\backslash \Bbb{H}$ is ramified.

Then apply [Riemann Hurwitz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula) to find the genus of $\Gamma\backslash \Bbb{H}^*$.

The numbers you need to know are $$n(\Gamma z)=|f^{-1}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}z)|, \qquad N=[SL_2(\Bbb{Z}):\Gamma]$$

Since $\Gamma$ is normal then each element of $\gamma\in \Gamma\backslash SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ is an automorphism $\gamma(\Gamma z)=\Gamma \gamma z$ of $\Gamma\backslash \Bbb{H}^*$ such that $f= f\circ \gamma$ and $\frac{N}{n(\Gamma z)}$ is the number of automorphisms leaving $\Gamma z$ fixed. Note that $n(\Gamma z)=n(\Gamma \gamma z)$.

$\frac{N}{n(\Gamma i\infty)}$ can be an integer, $\frac{N}{n(\Gamma i)}$ is either $1$ or $2$, and $\frac{N}{n(\Gamma e^{2i\pi/3})}$ is either $1$ or $3$.

Proof: again look at $\Bbb{H}\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\backslash \Bbb{H}$.